# Can client-side generated controls affect ViewState?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, viewstate

I have a page that generates new text `inputs`, `checkboxes`, `selects` with JavaScript. So none of these controls has `runat="server"` set.

I would like to know if these controls are sent to the server on PostBack and become part of the Viewstate, altering it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **yes, by assignment**.

Dynamically generated plain HTML elements in ASPX page will be treated as [LiteralControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) elements rather than [WebControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) elements, hence they don't affect `ViewState` directly like some ASP .NET server controls. However, since they're placed inside `form` tag (usually with `runat="server"` attribute), their values are posted together as postback event stage triggered by submitting the form, which identified as key-value pair in [Request.Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx) collection (the key is recognized by name attribute of literal HTML element).

Suppose you have dynamically generated text box with JS like this:

```
<input name="FirstName" type="text" />
```

Then you can retrieve its value using `Request.Form`:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form("FirstName")) Then
   Dim firstName As String = Request.Form("FirstName")
```

And, the important point, you can omit the string assignment above and assign literal text box value to `ViewState`:

```
ViewState("FirstName") = Request.Form("FirstName").ToString()
```

Note that only HTML server controls (e.g. `<input runat="server" />`) and ASP .NET server controls have control name directly accessible in code-behind and `ViewState` maintained automatically (unless having `EnableViewState` attribute set to `false`).

Additional `ViewState` reference:

[Understanding ASP.NET View State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Related issues:

[How to viewstate in normal HTML input in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436674/how-to-viewstate-in-normal-html-input-in-asp-net)

[Which controls have ViewState maintained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606887/which-controls-have-viewstate-maintained)

[viewstate for HTML control](https://forums.asp.net/t/1064646.aspx?viewstate%20for%20HTML%20control)

Comment: If one of the controls (asp:TextBox) is disabled with js and the form is sent on Postback, would that affect the viewstate?

Comment: Disabled control in client-side with JS certainly doesn't affect server side part, as long as it has name/ID attribute its value can be retrieved either using `Request.Form` (for HTML literal control) or `controlID.Value` (for both HTML & ASP.NET server control) and may affect `ViewState`.